# SharePoint 2016 - MySite Upgrade from SharePoint 2013 - Wrong URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, my-site, upgrade

I completed a SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 db attach upgrade.  I updated My Site host Url in SharePoint 2016 UPS My Site to the new site collection but Newsfeed, Onedrive and Sites are still point to the SharePoint 2013 url.

Example:

SharePoint 2013 My Site URL:  http://sharepoint2013.domain.com/mysite
SharePoint 2016 My Site URL: https://sharepoint2016.domain.com/mysite

Note: In SharePoint 2016 My Site Read Permission Level, I can add users, click Ok but going back in shows "No exact match was found. Click the item(s) that did not resolve for more options."  Same behavior with Secondary Owner under My Site Cleanup.

Also, I my employee directory is showing 0 people results in SharePoint 2016.

Any ideas on what I missed after upgrading My Sites in SharePoint 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the alternate access mapping URL in CA and host URL in web front end iis server... then check the **content source** URL in the search crawl - it might still refer to SharePoint 2013 URL.